# Derive character length for database field from Unicode code points length

Tags: sql-server, unicode

I have a process doing the following in Python

- Source data from Square API.
- Load into SQLAlchemy ORM Sessions
- Load into SQL Server

I am adding a new table and the source systems documentation includes the following note for several fields:

> This field has max length of ### Unicode code points.

The length amounts vary. I do not have samples of values that are the max length so that I could inspect them.  I have reviewed other answers trying to cobble together some sort of equation.  It seems the length might actually vary, but I just need max possible length.

Is there a way to calculate this?  If I just need to multiply by some factor, what would the factor be?

```
needed_nvarchar_field_length = unicode_code_points_length * some_factor
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I think "Unicode code point" is synonymous with a character so the max length is the number of characters regardless of the number of bytes needed for encoding.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks Dan!  I will operate off of that feedback.  I'm really quite unfamiliar with unicode and found it confusing trying to dive into.